# Anything after segment_1 in URL causes CSS not to load

Tags: ee2, templates, url, css

CSS is not loading if there is anything after segment_1. This includes a trailing slash or an entry id. This happens on ANY template on this site but not other sites on the same server with the same .htaccess.

EG: "...//example.com/projects/" or "...//example.com/projects/4" will not render CSS in browser

The template will still parse the EE tags but seems to not be sending the CSS to the broswer despite the  code showing in the rendered HTML.

Live example: "http://getyourtips.in/projects/"

Setup --

Template Group: projects

Template: index.html

Version: EE 2.6.1

CSS Theme: Unify (Bootstrap Based)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a forward slash to your assets.

Change this 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">`

to this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">`

Comment: Fixed. Thank you so much. That is the first time I have seen that. I wonder why it causes an issue since the path for the CSS in the rendered HTML is valid.

Comment: FYI: Just noticed that no slash before "assets" also causes the logo not to load. Strange because the Javascript loads without having a slash before "assets".

Comment: Scratch that last comment... The Javascript does NOT load with the leading slash before "assets"

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because if you omit the initial slash then the path is relative to the current page.

The first slash basically says, "start from the site root". So no matter where you are within the filesystem the link "/assets/css/style.css" will always resolve to the correct place.

If you are at "/mypage/something" and you call "assets/css/style.css" you are effectively looking for "/mypage/something/assets/css/style.css" which is going to be incorrect.

It's not an ExpressionEngine issue, it's a basic principle of how URLs and filesystems work.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explination.
However, this "theme" runs fine when it isn't processed through EE. If anything has a path statement , I need to have the leading slash. I wonder why this happens inside EE and not out?

Comment: Here is the theme: http://htmlstream.com/unify/page_home1.html  
I'm pretty sure that code has no leading slashs. It works just fine outside of EE.

Comment: Every page in that 'theme' is at the same level in the file system and so is also at the same level as the assets directory. If you have "segment_2" then your "pages" aren't at the same level. Again, this is nothing to do with EE really, it's just how filesystems work.

Comment: " If you have "segment_2" "  DOH! I just han't been thinking on that level. Upon further checking, it was the home page working that had me fooled at first. Thank You.